# How can I specify dynamically the ItemProcessor for a JSON Job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have different JSON files and need to read, process and write the containing JSON objects of a JSON array.

The output format (more specific: the output class) is for all files the same. Lets call it `OutputClass`. Hence the item processor is something like `ItemProcessor<X, OutPutClass>`. Where `X` is the class of the specific JSON file.

The difference between files are:

- The JSON array / the information is at a different position in every JSON file
- The structure of the JSON objects in the JSON array are different (the objects in file `a` have a different syntax than the ones in file `b`)

I already came across of `@StepScope` and was able to dynamically generate a reader (depending on job parameters) which starts reading at a different position in the JSON structure.

But I have no idea how to dynamically choose an ItemProcessor depending on the job parameters. Because I got many different JSON files and want to reduce the amount of code to write for each file.

Comment: `was able to dynamically generate a reader (depending on job parameters)` .. `I have no idea how to dynamically choose an ItemProcessor depending on the job parameters.`: Since you were able to do it for the reader, why don't you use the same approach for the processor? Can you share how you did it for the reader?

Comment: Yep. Can't remember why I didn't think about it. The dynamic ItemProcessor was the solution. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were able to create a dynamic item reader based on job parameters by using the a step-scoped bean (which is the way I would do it too), you can use the same approach to create a dynamic item processor as well.